# acct folder android

Tags: android, file, system, internal

What does the `/acct` folder in `android` file system hierarchy mean? I need to understand the file system hierarchy. Does the manipulation of this file inflict any harm?

Comment: There is no `/acct` directory in the root of any Android device that I have seen.

Comment: @CommonsWare - there is ,check out this [link](http://img.tapatalk.com/42574b6c-6409-8adc.jpg)

Comment: AFAIK, that is unique to your device or ROM mod supplier.

Comment: Well,does a typical linux filesystem have such a folder?

Comment: None that I have ever seen. For example, there is no `/acct` directory on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Well ,cant help but then wait for some more answers then ,thanks for notifying though

Comment: My mistake, there is an `acct/` directory in standard Android. I couldn't tell you what it does, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare-No probs ,will keep looking anyhow :) How about this question - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885670/cache-recovery-folder-in-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think acct means accounting from "CPU Accounting Controller".

[CPU Accounting Controller](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups/cpuacct.txt)

[cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)