# /cache/recovery folder in android

Tags: android, caching, recovery

What does the cache/recovery folder hold in the android filesystem? I have a single file inside it - `last_log` that seems to have the log infomation about the last bootup. Can somebody explain this in detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`/cache`** contains dex information about the apps installed on your device. This information is populated at the very first boot of Android. Android uncompresses each app, optimizes its launch, and save it into `/cache`. You should at least see one file per app with a weird name:

**`/recovery`** contains files needed to boot in recovery mode. Recovery mode is a special boot mode that allow you to (not limited):

- wipe /data,
- wipe /cache,
- install an update package

Some files contain commands that the recovery tool would execute if you ask so. For example, recovery mode is entered when you select **factory reset** on your device. When doing so, Android writes some commands to a file in `/recovery` and asks the system to reboot in recovery mode. When recovery program is being executed, it reads the file and executes the commands written. In this case (factory reset), it would erase `/data` and `/cache` and reboot.

Those links might be interesting to you:

- [What are ODEX files in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593527/what-are-odex-files-in-android)
- http://www.androidcentral.com/what-recovery-android-z
- http://marakana.com/s/post/1065/updating_android_os_via_ota (AOSP)
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1091508
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem.html (Java API)

Answer (score 3):

Make some supplements for **m-ric's**  answer:

1. Actually, when your device enter in recovery mode, recovery system will mount a swap partition named "**tmp**", which is half size of you device's RAM in general if you didn't set its size in **fstab** or any other places.
2. Then all your logs in recovery will saved in **tmp** partition at first. But when you quit recovery mode and boot to normal Android system, the **tmp** will not mount and just disappear. So to let developers get the logs in recovery mode, before quitting recovery mode, the recovery itself will copy logs from **tmp** partition to cache partition(**/cache/recovery/xxx**). Now you can get the recovery log in Android system.

Comment: Suppose recovery fails to copy the file for some reason (e.g. didn't exit cleanly). Is there another way to get this file?

Comment: In this situation, I am not sure for that, but maybe you can mount tmp partition in normal Android system and find the file.

Comment: Is there a way to copy those files to a host computer on a non-rooted device? I know how to read the logs on the screen in recovery mode, but not how to copy them to another machine.